# Chrome like tab control in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, tabcontrol, dock

I have a requirement in my project in which I am looking for several functionalities like -

- '+' Button at title to Add new tabs.
- Drag tab and after dropping at another location it becomes independent **floating** window(form).
- Dropping the floating window back in tabs collection area should convert that float window back in tab.
- Docking - When tab is dragged from tab collection, and moved to left/right etc, then that tab gets adjusted (dock) in that area.
- Deletion/Rearrangement of tabs.

Is there any control provider which can help in satisfying these requirement?

Comment: https://github.com/dockpanelsuite